# Как пропустить некоторые итерации в цикле for?

Tags: lua

Я хочу чтобы скрипт пропускал некоторые итерации.
Должно получиться (1, 2, 8, 9, 10)
Например:

```
for i = 1, 10 do
if i == 2 then i = 8 end
print(i) end
```

Comment: [Why does Lua have no "continue" statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3524970/4827341)

Answer (score 0):

Так не получится:

```
for i = 1, 10 do
if i == 2 then i = 8 end
print(i) end
```

В Lua, в отличие от других языков, каждый повтор цикла порождает свой экземпляр переменной цикла (это сделано специально для того, чтобы реализовать правильное замыкание, а не такое как в JS).
Текущий экземпляр переменной цикла живёт до конца тела цикла, а на следующем повторе цикла будет уже другая переменная, с тем же именем, инициализированная следующим значением.
Короче говоря, изнутри цикла влиять на логику переменной цикла (напр, пропускать значения) невозможно.
Придётся делать вот так:

```
for i = 1, 10 do
  if not (i >= 3 and i <= 7) then
    print(i) 
  end
end
```

Ну, или можно использовать циклы while или repeat с внешним счётчиком цикла:

```
local i = 0
while i < 10 do
  i = i + 1
  if i == 3 then i = 8 end
  print(i) 
end
```